# Can't read the content of a property file by using the relative path

Tags: java

My java class is residing in the folder `/webserver/tomcat-instance/webapps/shop/WEB-INF/classes/com/mobile/commons` but the actual property file is residing in the location 
`/webserver/tomcat-instance/webapps/shop/WEB-INF/classes/resources` directory. Now in my java file i put the relative path as `/WEB-INF/classes/resources/prop.properties` to read the intended file but every time i'm getting the FileNotFound Exception.

Please help me resolving this issue. What should i use as a relative path as i don't want to use the absolute path.

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: Any more information on how you try to read the file or do you want us to guess?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading it with

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/prop.properties");
```

**Update:**

```
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("resources/prop.properties");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Yes!!! the mentioned approach worked for me..Thanks a lot. I've one more question i.e how we can read the same property file by using the FileInputStream instead of InputStream?

Answer (score 1):

it's better to use

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/prop.properties")
```

Comment: It's better to get the context ClassLoader if you're loading Classes. I'm not sure how it will make any kind of difference in the case of reading a resource stream however.